# Pass input parameter as a filter to a column derived from table input parameter

Tags: hana

How to pass a input parameter (Date) as a filter condition to a column to a different input parameter which is derived from table type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from table where date = ?
```

Comment: SAP Hana queries are not the same the MSSQL ones, at the very least you need to include the backticks